# Why clean is not called in FormView after post?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

There is my view:

```
class SendTransfer(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    model = BankAccount
    form_class = SendTransferForm
    template_name = 'dashboard/send_transfer.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(SendTransfer, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(SendTransfer, self).get_object(queryset)

        if not obj.is_owner(self.request.user.citizen):
            raise Http404

        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        MoneyTransfer.objects.create(sender=self.object,
                                     receiver=data['receiver'],  # ModelChoiceField in the form
                                     total=data['total'],  # FloatField in the form, etc.
                                     when=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()),
                                     comment=data['comment'])
        return redirect('AccountDetail', self.object.pk)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        return {'sender': BankAccount.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']), 'user': self.request.user}
```

when form is submitting - I'm getting the same result as after get. Debugger says that clean() is not called but form_invalid is works. What is the problem?

Comment: Question edited. form_invalid is calling anyway. form.clean() is not calling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overridden `get_form_kwargs`, and now you are no longer passing `data` to the form. Without `data`, the form is unbound, so will never be valid.

It would be better to call `super()` first, update the kwargs, then return them.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(SendTransfer, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['sender'] = BankAccount.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']), 
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```